# Nt* api headers for user mode app

Tags: c++, c, header-files

I'm looking for header files for C/C++ which will contain ntdll.dll function definitions. I know those apis are for internal use and undocumented. There is such thing for pascal, I can't beleive there is no for C/C++, though I couldn't find any.

thanks

Comment: What part of "undocumented" is unclear to you?

Comment: @James, oh, really? How could I've guessed that :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should not be too hard to convert the ones for Pascal back to C. With a compiler like Embarcadero's C++Builder, you could have it done by the Delphi compiler that comes with it. Just ask someone with C++Builder to add the .pas file to a C++ project and a .hpp file will be generated, which is simply a .h file with a few extra settings for the use with Delphi and C++Builder. Remove the C++Builder specific parts, if any, and you're set.

FWIW, I have C++Builder. Where can one get the Pascal file?

Comment: Thank you Rudy. I don't want to take your precious time, there are lots of files :-). If you'll need it, it's called Jwa api or JwaNative I don't remember exactly. Thank you again, I will try it tomorrow probably and let you know the results :) +1 in the meantime

Comment: Ah, the JEDI Windows API conversions by Marcel van Brakel (we did some of these together and one of those is even by me) and others. I'll try to find the NT* APIs in there. They are probably just a small part (one file) of it.

Comment: respects my freinds, your library was a huuge help in my past project. Thank you very much for your effort :)

Answer (score 1):

Some of them are (for legal reasons I would assume) documented, but carry the following disclaimer:

> "... may be altered or unavailable in future versions of Windows.
>   Applications should use the alternate functions listed in this
>   topic.".

For Example [NtQuerySystemInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724509%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Headers, although I'm not sure how complete, are included in the [Windows Driver Kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487428).